# Remove items from array dynamically

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a huge array of XML nodes, sometimes up to 400k items. I use where-object to to select items based on Type attribute. My problem is that it takes quite some time to walk over these items and it would be easier if I could remove items I have just selected from array, so that array would be smaller for next object. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$subset = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "2"}
'prosess ItemType 2'

$subset = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "4"}
'prosess ItemType 4'

$subset = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "8"}
'prosess ItemType 8'
```

Problem is that every time I have to iterate over `$items` again, instead of iterating over what is remaining from previous `where-object`

It also doesn't help that where-object is a single thread operation and is executed only on one core

What I was thinking about is something like this, but I'm not sure if it will perform better:

```
$subset = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "2"}
$items = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -ne "2"}
'prosess ItemType 2'

$subset = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "4"}
$items = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -ne "4"}
'prosess ItemType 4'

$subset = $items | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "8"}
'prosess ItemType 8'
```

Comment: Have you considered using a linked-list instead of an array?  May be more efficient considering the amount of elements is approaching 400k.  Easier to remove elements from the middle.http://www.techrepublic.com/article/deciding-whether-to-use-arrays-or-linked-lists/1050183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `Select-Xml` cmdlet or the XmlDocument.SelectNodes method? Querying XML via its native methods(using XPath), should perform much faster than `Where-Object`.

Comment: It is a very good idea, I will try it and report how it goes, thanks

Comment: You were right it takes just 15 seconds with SelectNodes vs 2.5 minutes with Where-Object

Comment: Worth every millisecond of it ;)